# How to Convert String "YYYY/MM/DD" Formatted Date to a VARIANT Type Date and Vice-versa

Tags: c++, excel, com

How can I convert a "YYYY/MM/DD" formatted date to a VARIANT type date and vice-versa in C++?

**EDIT**

VARIANT VT_DATE Type passed by VBA code into an automation COM written in c++

Comment: You need to specify where that VARIANT type comes from. Is it Win32-specific?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try via `CComVariant` ?

E.g. : (from string to date)

```
VARIANT myVBDate;
CComVariant myDate("YYYY/MM/DD date");
if (SUCCEEDED(myDate.ChangeType(VT_DATE)) && SUCCEEDED(myDate.Detach(&myVBDate)))
{
    // do something with myVBDate
}
```